# Homebrew Cask, Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/shared/charm

Tags: macos, homebrew, homebrew-cask

Among the Homebrew casks on my Apple Silicon Mac, via `brew list --casks`, I can see that `pycharm-ce` (PyCharm CE) is listed.

However, the application no longer exists at `/Applications/PyCharm CE.app`, probably after a previously failed update attempt via Homebrew cask.

If I attempt any of the following:

- `brew reinstall --cask pycharm-ce`
- `brew uninstall --cask pycharm-ce`

I get an `No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen` error like:

```
==> Uninstalling Cask pycharm-ce
Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/shared/charm
```

If I attempt to download and install the PyCharm `.dmg` manually from their website, and then attempt to uninstall cask:

- `brew uninstall --zap pycharm-ce`

I get the same `No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen` error, after it has removed the `.app`:

```
brew uninstall --zap pycharm-ce
==> Implied `brew uninstall --cask pycharm-ce`
==> Backing App 'PyCharm CE.app' up to '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/pycharm-ce/2022.1.3,221.5921.27/PyCharm CE.app'
==> Removing App '/Applications/PyCharm CE.app'
Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/shared/charm
```

If I simply run `brew install --cask pycharm-ce`, Homebrew thinks the application is already installed.

How can I clean up this cask, and reinstall PyCharm CE?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if this is the correct solution – but it worked for me to simply delete the folder which belongs to the problematic install (`pycharm-ce`) from `Caskroom` *(the location under `/opt/` is for Homebrew on Apple Silicon)*:

```
cd /opt/homebrew/Caskroom
rm -rf pycharm-ce
```

Then reinstall it again:

```
brew install --cask pycharm-ce
```